# CSS. Измененить цвет при нажатии и сохранить изменённое значение

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
/* Элемент меняет цвет при наведении на него */
button.yt-icon-button:hover {
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #ff0087;
}

/* Элемент меняет цвет во время нажатия на доли секунд.  */
button.yt-icon-button:active {
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #01a715;


/* Элемент меняет цвет после нажатия, но стоит потом куда-то кликнуть и изменённый цвет заменяется на цвет по умолчанию. */
button.yt-icon-button:focus {
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #01a715;
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при клике изменялся цвет элемента и **не изменялся** на дефолт при клике на другое место.

---

Попробовала добавить код от Vadizar.

Получается вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но когда я добавляю **нижнее**, так как мне **не нужно** изменение фона. Я с фоном не работаю :

```
button { 
color: #ff9000 !important; 
transition: color 9999999s
} 

button:active { 
color: green;
transition: color 0s 
}
```

у меня "палец вверх" **не становится** зелёным. Почему ?

И ещё:

Почему подсветка кода от Vadizar такая:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*слово background выделяется зелёным*

А при моём (скорей всего неправильном) варианте такая:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*слово color не выделяется зелёным*

И почему в конец после transition не добавляется `;` ?

Comment: Уберите !important и будет работать.

Comment: Точку с запятой не добавляю, потому что последнее свойство не обязательно закрывать.

Comment: Выделение значение цветом полностью регулируется в вашей IDE. Хоть радугой подсветку сделайте. Она нужна лишь для лучшего визуального восприятия.

Comment: Так как ваш ответ более близок к результату - приму. Не хватает объяснений, а именно почему после такого финта при нажатии активируется зёлёный цвет , а при повторном клике на этот же элемент цвет не возвращается на дефолтный. Надо бы мне начать практиковать вопросы и ответы с gif - ками...

Comment: Вся загадка кроется в значении transition 9999999s. Цвет вернется обратно, но только через 2777 часа. При повторном клике на кнопку счетчик сброситься и начнет счет заново. Советую начать изучать основы HTML и CSS. Тогда придет понимание и сможете сами такие хаки делать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Решение на чистом `CSS` без хаков с `input`:

```css
 
button {
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  padding: 1.2rem 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: background 9999999s;
}

button:active {
  background: red;
  transition: background 0s;
}
```

```html
<button>Click</button>
```

Вся загадка кроется в значении `transition: 9999999s`. Цвет постепенно будет возвращаться к исходному значению в течении 2777 часов. При повторном клике на кнопку счётчик перезапустится.

Я не настаиваю на том, что это верный подход, и полностью согласен с решением [St1myL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/280567/st1myl). Тем не менее, данный пример показывает, на что способен `CSS` при извращенном воображении и может быть полезен в некоторых случаях, когда невозможно использовать `JS` и не подходит метод с `input`.

Comment: Гениально...)))

Comment: А по сути очень простое решение)

Comment: Некрасивое решение = Правильное решение:)

Comment: `button {
  color: #ff9000 !important;
  transition: color 9999999s
}

button:active {
  color: green;
  transition: color 0s
}` не работает . А с background работает.

Comment: Уберите  !important

Comment: Ты хотя  бы объяснил, что через `9999999` секунд  `background` вернет исходный цвет))))  Ну и пример....  И на кой  `JS` создали... ) Универсальное решение `transition: background 9999999s`

Comment: @Air в комментариях к вопросу ещё вчера всё объяснил.

Comment: К transition я бы дописал `step-end`.

Comment: @Air маловероятно, что страница будет открыта хотя бы час, не то чтобы больше суток.

Comment: А это ж оно где-то в ядре цепляет на кнопку обработчик который каждую `мс` по немного превращает кнопку из #000 в #f00 Ппц оно прожорливое по идеи должно быть) А если в html таких кнопок с этим классом целое меню....

Comment: @BlackStar1991 CSS-анимации быстрее JS.

Answer (score 6):

#### Вариант на `JavaScript`

Добавлять класс со стилем при клике на кнопку:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.classList.add("active");
});
```

```css
button {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 1.2rem 2rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click</button>
```

#### Вариант на чистом `HTML/CSS`

Завязаться на значение `:checked` у `<input type="radio">`:

```css
input[type=radio] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  z-index: -1;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

label {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  background: black;
  margin: 0 0 .5em 0;
  padding: 1em 2em;
}

input[type=radio]:checked~label {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="button">
<label for="button">Click</label>
```

Comment: Я пишу для Stylish расширения. Без JS такое не делается ?

Comment: @Tanya, добавил вариант на `CSS`.

Comment: @Tanya, если вам помог ответ, отметьте его решением:)

Comment: Я его должна понять и применить , и только тогда я отмечу ответ решением. В любом случае спасибо. :)

Comment: @Tanya, благодарю, не поймите неправильно, иногда пользователи забывают отметить, поэтому напоминаю таким образом)

Comment: Я ваше решение не понимаю. Не могли бы вы объяснить как-то иначе по простому. Я пытаюсь изменить цвет кнопки лайка на Youtube при нажатии на него. Возможно ли такое, если сайт не принадлежит мне ?

Comment: @Tanya, тогда моё второе решение вам не поможет:)) Там `svg`-иконки, к которым идёт привязка стилей `yt-icon`

Comment: @Duoxx, прошу прощения, где я показался алчным? Это было лишь напоминание. Напоминал не раз об этом другим авторам вопросов, кто-то отреагирует, а кто-то пройдёт мимо. Ещё одно уточнение, прочитайте заново мой прошлый комментарий, а именно ключевые слова - "Если вам помог ответ", в данном случае автору вопроса не слишком подошёл мой ответ, как я сам ответил выше, где же алчность? Разве я прямым текстом сказал, что нужно отметить именно мой ответ?